# Finding ratio based on count in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to list each teams ratio of matches lost from total matches played.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
select teams.name as Name,
Lost
from teams
join matches on teams.name in (matches.home, matches.away)
group by teams.name
having (1 - (matches.winner / (count (matches.home) + count (matches.away)))) as Lost;
```

Is the problem with the way I wrote the function in the last line?

Relational diagram for reference:

[image]

Comment: I just +1 your question because it isn't that bad, although you do need to provide the error you are receiving rather than it doesn't work.

Comment: I find your ER model "format" rather confusing to be honest. I have never seen such a graphical representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause is used to filter the resultset after any grouping has occured, not to define functions.
You need to write all the logic for the columns that you need returned within the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT  T.NAME
        ,COUNT(M.*) AS MATCHES_PLAYED
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN M.WINNER = T.NAME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WINS
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN M.WINNER = T.NAME THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS LOSSES
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN M.WINNER = T.NAME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(M.*) AS WIN_PERCENT
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN M.WINNER = T.NAME THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)/COUNT(M.*) AS LOSS_PERCENT
FROM    TEAMS T
INNER JOIN
        MATCHES M
ON      T.NAME = M.HOME
OR      T.NAME = M.AWAY        
GROUP BY
        T.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting an error for `count(m.*)`, is there any other way to write it? (the error is: `invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`)

Comment: try `count(m.ID)` in all three instances.